# Type conversion - two strings to int on power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

On Power BI, how would I convert any row that is "Processed" OR "New" in my Status column, to be represented by a 1 in the new column (using DAX)?

Thanks!

Comment: In the query editor or using DAX?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify, but DAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an `IF()` function in a new calculated column.

```
NewCol = IF(Table1[Status] = "Processed" || Table1[Status] = "New", 1, 0)
```

You can also use the `IN` syntax instead of having multiple conditionals.

```
NewCol = IF(Table1[Status] IN {"Processed", "New"}, 1, 0)
```